# what does "blow off" mean in the girl who blew off PJ

Tags: phrasal-verbs

This is from *Good Luck Charlie*.

PJ met a girl Emma at the park for the first time. PJ had a big crush on her. Emma gave him her phone number. Later, by accident, PJ brought home the baby who had been with Emma, and Emma took back to her home the baby who had been with PJ. PJ tried to call Emma, but found Emma gave him a fake number.

The sister Teddy said, "Come on, let's go to the park."

The younger brother Gabe said,

> to meet the girl who *blew off* PJ. I'm there.

What does "blew off" mean? I've found three definitions in thefreedictionary.com.

1. slang To ignore or intentionally avoid a person, planned event, or responsibility, often to do something frivolous instead.
2. To deceive or swindle someone or something.
3. To ignore someone in order to end a romantic or other relationship

Which definition best fits the context? I guess it's number 2. Do you agree? Is this usage common?

Comment: It's #1. By giving him a fake number, she blew him off.

Comment: Why is it not #2? The first says to ignore to avoid a person, but Teddy does not ignore or avoid PJ.

Comment: The girl blew off PJ. That's the phrase. She blew off PJ by giving him a fake number.